# Developing a reader program which can read approximately all types of document files

Tags: java, android

Hey friends i am a student and i am trying to design a reader program which can read all type of document files (e.g. .doc, .text, .pdf, etc) for my android phone, 
This is my first serious project and i don't know what i need to do, also tell me it is reliable or not ?
please tell me where from i should start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, don't start.

Reading *all* types of document files is impossible.  Even *just* reading ".doc" and ".pdf" would be such a big programming task that it could take you years to accomplish ... depending of course on what you mean by "reading".

Pick something more realistic for your first serious project.

---

And think on this.  If what you were planning on attempting was even slightly easy, someone else would already have implemented it for Android.  Such a tool would be very useful, and surely someone else would have already implemented ... if it was feasible.

Comment: So if i precise it only to a pdf reader then what do you say

Comment: 1) Still a hard job. 2) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en